# How to find the eigenvalues of $O$ in the following integral equation?

Tags: eigenvalue

$$O=\exp\left(x^TAx +x'^T B x'+x^TCx'+x'^TDx\right)$$

Where $x^T=(x_0,x_1,..,x_{n-1})$, $x'^T=(x'_0,x'_1,..,x'_{n-1})$ and $A,B,C,D$ are complex square $n\times n$ matrices. The column matrices x and x' consists of real entries. Also, $A^\dagger=B$ and $C\&D$ are Hermitian. I need to know a proper eigenfunction to solve for $\lambda_n$the following equation:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} O f(x')_n\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} dx'_i=\lambda_n f(x)_n$$

Srednicki solved a similar problem in the paper Entropy and Area: https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9303048.pdf, where he assumed an eigenfunction $f(x)_n=H_n(\sqrt a x)$ where $H_n$ is the nth Hermite polynomial. I am wondering if a similar $f(x)_n$ exists in this case.

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_theory) might be useful.

Comment: Can identifying $O$ as related to propagator/green function of Euclidean $N-$dimensional Harmonic oscillator help atleast for some restricted cases?